# Find Credit Card Number in XML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, vb.net

I have a Credit Card Number in an XML Message and I want to use a regex to find the Credit Card Number and encrypt it.  All numbers are 16 characters long and they are not always in the same place in the xml, so basically I think I just need to find a string that is 16 characters and decrypt it, but I am not sure how.

Example:

```
<Message>
<PaymentInfo>
<CCNumber>333333333333333</CCNumber>
</PaymentInfo>
</Message>
```

Another way may be:

```
<Message>
<CardInfo>
<CreditNumber>333333333333333</CreditNumber>
</CardInfo>
</Message>
```

Would this solution work, it is in VB though because the original code was VB.

```
 Public Shared Function EncryptXmlLog(xml As String) As String
 'Get possible credit card numbers (13 - 16 characters)

 Dim creditCardNumbers As MatchCollection = Matches(xml, "\b\d{13,16}\b")

 For Each creditCardNumber As RegularExpressions.Match In creditCardNumbers
     xml = xml.Replace(creditCardNumber.Value, Encrypt(creditCardNumber.Value))
 Next

 Return xml
 End Function
```

Comment: Need more information. Your question is very vague. Why not use `XmlDocument` class? can you post an example `XML` format?

Comment: Do you have an example of the xml? Is it structured so that the elements containing the credit numbers are identifiable in a predictable fashion?

Comment: @PHeiberg - No, every xml is different, that is why I mentioned that they are not always in the same place. In some places they may be between <ccnumber></ccnumber> and in others it might be <creditcard></creditcard>

Comment: It would be nice to get an explanation of why this is down-voted

Comment: Every hear of the Mod10 Function... It's a great way to detect if a string of 16 digits is an actual POSSIBLE credit card number of 16/15 or 13 digits

Comment: @Jack - I added a couple examples, but the ways it is stored is many more than just the two I just posted. I am using XmlDocument, the issue is is that I have to send a decrypted credit card to the client, but after that I store the xml message in a database log table where I need to find the 16 digit number and decrypt it for storage.

Comment: @Relic- I have never heard of the Mod10 function, but The bigger issue is not determining if a number is a credit card number or not, it is determining how to find it in a huge xml file.

Comment: Why is your schema so different every time?

Comment: @simchona - Because these are xml messages sent to hotel property management systems and they don't have a standard.  It is not my schema, but their schema I must adapt to.

Comment: I don't understand how this is too localized.  In other words, how do you find a 16 character number in an xml string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(\d{16}|\d{15}|\d{13})` will match any digit sets of 16, 15, or 13

However I must know why you don't just commonize your XML doc before parsing. If there are multiple docs, you should have a conditional parser of some kind.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what cards have 14 or 13 digits?

Comment: Mastercard and American Express... Check out that Mod10 algorithm.
And: http://money.howstuffworks.com/personal-finance/debt-management/credit-card1.htm

Comment: So American Express has 15, but Master Card has 16

Comment: I can't commonize the xml because each xml message is sent to a different hotel property management system and they expect the xml in different formats.  There is a group that is trying to standardize it, but no one wants to follow it.

Comment: yeah, I'd use the conditional, and old MasterCards do have 13... So use that regex to parse for 13->16 digits, then run the MOD10 on them to see if it fits the credit card standard

Comment: I am not concerned if it is valid, so would this work:  \b\d{13,16}\b

Comment: Actually the ONLY way to make sure that string of numbers up to 16 digits is a Credit Card at all is running it through the MOD10 algorithm. The regex is just checking the length of digits in a row... However, you could strict down the regex to say only 16 digits after a ">" and before a "</" so it grabbed only digits sets that were inside tags: (>(\d{13}|\d{15}|\d{16})<\/)

Comment: Disregard if it is a credit card number or not, could I use \b\d{13-16}\b to find strings 13 - 16 characters long

Comment: yes, but that's painfully vague for what you're trying to accomplish, and RegEx has a way of picking up patterns not intended, that's why I made my final suggestion so strict.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
   var match = Regex.Match(xmlStrin, @">(\d{16})<"); 
   var number = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: I will give this a shot.  Will this match only 16, not less or more?

Comment: Exactly 16 digits 0-9, between > and < characteres.

Comment: I am assuming based on Relic's answer that I could do @">(\d{16}|\d{14}|\d{13})<

Comment: Also I believe this would work as well:  \b\d{13,16}\b, correct?

Comment: No.it matches `15` digits as well.

Comment: One other thing, the credit card number can appear multiple times, how would I find all occurrences?

Comment: for find all occurrences, you can use `Regex.Matches()` instead of `Regex.Match()`. Check out:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches%28v=vs.71%29.aspx